# How do I generate a grid of randomized tiles in an Android Activity given 4 different image files?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating a grid in an android activity of 9 tiles by 14 tiles each one being a random choice between 1 out of 4 different tile types: desert, grass, rock and water.

I've tried doing a nested for loop and editing the tiles through the findViewById() function.   Every tile has a unique ID corresponding to its location, but I cannot find a way to link the numbers in the for loop to the tile location ex: R.id.tile+i+j

```java
    protected void randomizeTiles(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        ArrayList<Class <? extends GenericTile>> tileTypes
                = new ArrayList<Class <? extends GenericTile>>();
        tileTypes.add(0, Desert.class);
        tileTypes.add(1, Grass.class);
        tileTypes.add(2, Rock.class);
        tileTypes.add(3, Water.class);

        this.boardLayout = new GenericTile[9][13];

        AssetManager manager;
        manager = getAssets();

        for(int i=0; i < 13; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < 9; j++){
                int n = rand.nextInt(4);
                this.boardLayout[j][i] = (GenericTile) tileTypes.get(n).newInstance();
                ImageView tilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tile11);
                InputStream open;
                try{
                    open = manager.open(this.boardLayout[j][i].path);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
                    // Assign the bitmap to an ImageView in this layout
                    tilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

```xml
 <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="9"
        android:rowCount="14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins">

        <!-- row 1 -->

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile15"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile16"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile18"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile19"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

.............................

        <!-- row 13 -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile131"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile132"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile133"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile134"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile135"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile136"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile137"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile138"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tile139"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/desert"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/desert" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>
```

The current code only randomizes one of the tiles and the rest are set to the default desert image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Patrick to StackOverflow.

It seems you face an architectural problem: "How will I mirror the `i`s and `j`s of the for loops to a 9x13 grid of ImageViews".

It can be tackled with various techniques. I give you a simple one here:

Create a 9x13 Array that contains all your ImageViews. So getting `fooArrayOfImageViews[0][12]` will give you the top-right ImageView. Lines:

```
 this.boardLayout[j][i] = (GenericTile) tileTypes.get(n).newInstance();
 ImageView tilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tile11);
 .....
 tilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

, become

```
 this.boardLayout[j][i] = (GenericTile) tileTypes.get(n).newInstance();
 ImageView tilePic = fooArrayOfImageViews[j][i];
 .....
 tilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Hope it guided you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using the method of creating an array for the imageviews that you gave.  I had to hard code all the initiailization rather than loop through it which is kind of a pain, but it works now.